# Create a shorter link with meta rel="shortlink"

Tags: html, meta, short

How can I use this sort of meta for all pages of my website:

```
<link rel="shortlink" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/?p=12">
```

My goal is to have shorter link when I share my pages, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide what Content Management System (CMS) or framework you're using to manage your website? The platform that you use to add and manage pages on your website will determine the best way to generate the shortlink URL, and also how to put it into your page.

Typically you would generate a "short" URL (i.e. a [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) or [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com/)), either manually or automatically via your website platform, and then include it as the `meta` information in each of your pages. A good website platform would automate all of this for you to make it easier.

For example, if your site was using Wordpress, there is an inbuilt function when editing pages to produce a `http://wp.me/` shortened URL (see [Wordpress.com > Support > Shortlinks](https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortlinks/) for further Wordpress specific instructions).

If you can provide more information about your website's platform then more specific instructions can be provided.